# Extra refresh after a submit

Tags: grails, refresh, form-submit, gsp, submit-button

I know that whenever you submit a form, you will refresh a page. But is there a way of using javascript or whatsoever that allows the webpage to refresh one more time after a submit button is being input?

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds a bit ad-hoc, you could make your submit go toward a new action in your controller that just forwards to the view you want.

Comment: Okay, erm because what I'm facing now is that my EDIT page. After pressing the submit button which is the UPDATE button. The page refreshes and the values shown are before updated. However, when i refresh ONE more time, the updated value is shown. Thats why i wanted to do an extra refresh after pressing the submit button.

Comment: sorry, but it sounds like you have bigger issues looming. i suggest you restructure your programme a bit (like i suggested below) and you will see that this kind of problem goes away.

Take a generated controller as your example.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that what you need to implement is the Post, Redirect, Get pattern, which is the recommended way in Grails applications. if you type grails generate-controller [somedomainclassname], you will see that that controller actually employs this pattern.

It works as follows:

1. Your form submits to a action inside a controller, let's call it `save()`
2. Your `save()` action then performs the necessary operations to actually save the object, when it is done, it sends the browser a 'redirect', much like this: `redirect(action: "show", id: mySavedObject.id)`
3. This will cause the browser to issue a GET for the url /mycontroller/show/{id}
4. That request is picked up by the `show` action of your controller. It then goes on to display the object that was just created.

This approach plays well with HTTP semantics and avoids annoying "do you want to repost your form data" questions for the end user.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did a post action, but what I need is an EXTRA refresh after the POST action.

Comment: @user1681961 just do what Hans wrote, that should take care of your problem!